# Revert select menu change

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have an input that takes a number and a select menu with the unit of time. Using the select menu you can change the unit which will convert the input value. When the conversion is not possible to 0 decimal places I want to revert the select menu to the previous option.

This works as expected except the select menu reverting. My binding value changes but not the displayed option. I can only get it to change with a setTimeout() which makes the selected option flicker back to the previous option.

How can I get this to revert without using a setTimeout?

html for component

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div [formGroup]="form">
        <label for="label" id="programming-details" class="label">{{label}}</label>
        <input type="text" hidden="hidden" [(ngModel)]="msCounterValue" [formControlName]="formControlName" />
    </div>
    <input type="number"
           class="input-time" 
           [(ngModel)]="counterValue"
           min="{{minValue}}"
           max="{{maxValue}}"
           (keyup)="inputValueChange()"
           pattern="{{regex}}"
           (change)="inputValueChange()"
           required="{{required}}" />
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" ng-init="selectedValue.name" name="selectUnitType" (ngModelChange)="selectValueChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let name of UnitTypes" [ngValue]="name">
            {{name.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

ts component method

```
selectValueChange(event: any) {
        //Do the conversion asked for and get the value.
        var displayValue = this.timeDurationFilterHelper.Convert(this.counterValue, this.selectedValue.name, this.lastValue.name);
        //Check to see if the new value is a whole number. If it is update UI.
        if (displayValue % 1 == 0) {
            this.lastValue = this.selectedValue;
            this.counterValue = displayValue;
        }
        //Temporary fix added in using setTimeout
        else {
            var lastValueIndex = this.lastValue.Index;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.selectedValue = this.UnitTypes[lastValueIndex], 1
            });
        }
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Animation of changes is all the rage, just tell everyone it's a feature…

Comment: In your template, there are two places with `(change)`, but for `selectValueChange`, you use `(ngModelChange)`. Is there specific reason for that? Have you try with `(change)` also?

Comment: @JohnSiu, yes I tried with (change), it had the same issue.